# How to set up serving of pre-gzipped with web essentials / IIS ?

Tags: iis, http-headers, gzip, web-essentials

Web Essentials for Visual Studio 2012 just hit version 3.0 where they support generation of pre-gzipped files, but I can't figure out how to make it work? Do I have to add some http headers or something in IIS or something specific for css / js files in the web.config?